# Изменение состояния переменной в течении цикла

Tags: python, циклы

Допустим есть цикл:

```
for i in range (15):
```

И список с переменной:

```
d = ['d', 'e', 'n']
f = d[0]
```

Как мне по простому сделать так, чтобы переменная `f` меняла свои состояния принимая значения из `d` в течении цикла?

Comment: какой критерий "состояния" должен быть? случайное, расчетное?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

способ 1 (лучше не придумать):

```
d = ['d', 'e', 'n']
for i in range(15):
    print(d[i % len(d)])
```

способ 2:

```
d = ['d', 'e', 'n']
for i in zip(range(15), d * 15):
    print(i[1])
```

тут конечно для коротких массивов нормально, а вот для огромных - нет ибо память будет сжираться (например цикл до миллиарда)

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
d = ['d', 'e', 'n']
for i in range(15):
    f = d[i % len(d)]
    print(f)
```